# Why cant the scanner be made static

Tags: java

I understand why we have to create the scanner object, mainly to set the state of the scanner and to use its non-static methods. My question is couldn't we have made the scanner static and set the state of the scanner using private static variables?

Comment: And what if you need more than one scanner?

Comment: Well, that's true I am a beginner. Was just trying to think why you couldn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One major purpose of instance-based values is to allow multiple objects to exist, and track different states, at the same time. So if you had a Scanner that was reading input from two different files or devices at the same time, they would need to have their own individual states that don't interfere with each other.

There are other, more complex, reasons as well, such as allowing the Scanner to implement the `Iterator<String>` class, which it could not do with static methods.